# defining the type of a function- int and float on haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a problem with defining the type of a function. In the cases of 1, 10, 11 and 12, I insert an Int and return a float, but in the case in which I insert an Int and return an Int the types doesn't match.
I tried with 
pointsForSeventy:: Int->Float and also with pointsForSeventy:: Real a-> Int->a (I thought this one would work because Integrals and Fractionals are inside the Real numbers)

```
pointsForSeventy 1 = 5.5
pointsForSeventy 10 = 0.5
pointsForSeventy 11 = 0.5
pointsForSeventy 12 = 0.5
pointsForSeventy a = a
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your second idea is syntactically broken and should be `pointsForSeventy :: Real a => Int -> a` meaning it is a function from `Int` to `a` where `a` is an instance of `Real`.  Notice the fat arrow after the constraint (`=>` not `->`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an explicit conversion:

```
pointsForSeventy 1 = 5.5
pointsForSeventy 10 = 0.5
pointsForSeventy 11 = 0.5
pointsForSeventy 12 = 0.5
pointsForSeventy a = fromIntegral a
```

Unlike several other programming languages, Haskell will never automatically perform automatic or implicit conversion between numeric types.

On the other hand, numeric *literals* belong to any numeric type. E.g. `1/2*0.5 :: Double` will return `0.25` since all the three literals are `Double`s. In some languages like C, instead, `1/2*0.5` evaluates to `0` since `1/2` is integer division (!), and evaluates to `0`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem is that I need to clarify it in this way pointsForSeventy ::  ->

Comment: @cde33 You can't fix that at the type level, unless you let `pointsForSeventy :: Double -> Double` or something similar, involving the same floating point type for both input and output.

Answer (score 4):

Haskell is a statically typed language. So that means that the return type can *not* depend on the *value* of the input.

An idea might be to convert the `Int` into a `Float` by using [`fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral):

```
pointsForSeventy :: Int -> Float
pointsForSeventy 1 = 5.5
pointsForSeventy 10 = 0.5
pointsForSeventy 11 = 0.5
pointsForSeventy 12 = 0.5
pointsForSeventy a = fromIntegral a
```

In case you want to treat the `Int` case different from the `Float` case, you can also use [`Either`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t:Either):

```
pointsForSeventy :: Int -> Either Float Int
pointsForSeventy 1 = Left 5.5
pointsForSeventy 10 = Left 0.5
pointsForSeventy 11 = Left 0.5
pointsForSeventy 12 = Left 0.5
pointsForSeventy a = Right a
```